# \citealp putting parentheses in citation inappropriately

Tags: citing, natbib

I am using WinEdt with MikTeX 2.9 in a Windows 7 environment.

I am having issues being able to get text in parentheses working correctly with a citation, specifically that when the document prints to PDF I get extraneous parentheses that should be removed by the `natbib` command I am using.

I wish to have the following text:

```
(cited in Axelrod 1997)
```

But I keep getting:

```
(cited in Axelrod (1997))
```

I have tried using two methods to remove the extraneous pair of brackets. First I tried:

```
\citep[cited in]{Axelrod2}
```

and then I tried:

```
\citetext{cited in \citealp{Axelrod2}}
```

but both give me the same result: two sets of parentheses.

Could someone please advise me where I am going wrong? I have the `natbib` reference document, and I was copying from the examples in there.

I am using a document template created for my university and I have the following packages and options being loaded:

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[a4paper,layout=a4paper,
        bindingoffset=4cm,left=0cm,right=2cm,
        head=2.5cm, bmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[round]{natbib} 
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}
\usepackage{cleveref}
```

Comment: Hi there, I have changed the loading order to put `cleveref` last and used your `\citealt` suggestion. This removed the extra brackets, and inserted a comma between the author and the year. I seem to be experiencing some weird effects with the `natbib` package. I can live with the comma. If you put your suggestion as an answer, I can vote it as such. :)

Comment: In this case `\citep[cited in][]{Axelrod2}` seems like a good way to go.

Comment: Anyway, `\citetext{cited in \citealp{Axelrod2}}` should only produce one pair of parentheses. I could not reproduce the output you describe in the question with the code shown so far. It should work. Something else must be going on.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `natbib` package provides the following four basic citation commands: `\citet`, `\citep`, `\citealt`, and `\citealp`.

When using an author-year citation style, the output of these commands looks like this (assuming that (i) the key `axel97` points to an entry written by Axelrod in 1997 and (ii) one uses the `plainnat` or similar bibliography style):

[image]

Since you're looking to typeset the citation without parentheses and commas, you should use the command `\citealt`.

If you keep getting different results, try loading the `natbib` package either earlier or later in the preamble (while taking care to load the `cleveref` package *last*).