# Brackets in citing-style?

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib, brackets

I have the following LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 
        12pt,                               
        bibliography=totoc,     
        index=totoc,    
        abstracton,     
        headsepline,    
        ]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{latexsym}           
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}   
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}   

\usepackage [round,authoryear] {natbib}

\usepackage[bookmarksopen,hyperfootnotes=false,pdftitle=test, pdfauthor=test,pdfsubject=test]{hyperref}


\begin{document}        
Here comes a cite to literature\footnote{\citep[p. 53]{LathamWatkins:2011}.}.           
\bibliographystyle{autorjahrdidiDE}  
\bibliography{Bibref}

\end{document}
```

In my Bibre.bib I have the following entry:

```
   @Misc{LathamWatkins:2011,
      author =       {Latham\&Watkins},
      title =        "Regulatory Capital Reform under Basel 3",
     note = "available: \nolinkurl{http://www.garp.org/media/583507/regulatorycapitalreformbaseliii_nicolaides032311.pdf} (access on 05.03.2013, creation 24.03.2011)",
      year = "2011",
    }
```

This creates a cite entry at the bottom of the page like this:

^1(Latham&Watkins, 2011, p. 53)

See the screenshot I add:

[image: Te]

I do not want to have the brackets! What do I have to change, that the brackets () disappear?

EDIT (regarding the first answer):
\cite does not change anything, \citet looks like the following:

[image: te]

But is it possible to have no brackets at all? This would be quite important to me, since I am setting an important document and I would prefer to have no brackets at all.

Comment: If you do not want the brackets, use `\cite` instead of `\citep`.

Comment: Note this applies to other natbib bibliography styles such as `plainnat`, rather than just `autorjahrdidiDE`.

Comment: This has been asked at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102532/15925 before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\citealt` instead of `\citep`, `\cite` etc. will do it.  See [this reference sheet](http://merkel.zoneo.net/Latex/natbib.php) or the wikibook.

An alternative method, and what I would use for consistency throughout the document is the specify `\bibpunct{}{}{,}{a}{,}{,}`.  For details see [the wikibook entry](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management#Natbib) but the first 2 empty braces specify that no "bracket" is to be used.

Comment: one further question: How can I fastly change all those commands to \citealt, I am using a large document with a lot of pages? So something like search and substitute with...

Answer (score 1):

Try `\cite` and `\citet` instead of `\citep`. All three commands do different things.

Comment: I answered before I noticed @Corentin's comment. Sorry for the duplication.

Comment: \cite does not change anything, but \citet changes the brackets into Latham&Watkins (2011, p. 53). But is it possible to have no brackets at all?

Comment: `\cite` is either `\citet` or `\citep` depending on the citation mode.

Comment: I hadn't realised that they are equivalent in natbib. I use biblatex myself. Try `\citealt` and `\citealp`, which in natbib are `\citet` and `\citep` without parentheses respectively.