# Mimic \parencites using bibtex

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I need to have two references within parenthesis separated by some text (see [\citep for multiple references separated by text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174117/citep-for-multiple-references-separated-by-text)) so it should look like:

> (this is the first source Smith 2000; and also see Smith 2013 for more)

This is the command I think I'd need:

```
\parencites[this is the first source][]{Smith_2000}[; and also see][for more]{Smith_2013}
```

but I'm using a template that relies on `natbib` and a custom `.bst` file so I'm stuck using `bibtex`.
This means I can't use the `\parencites` command which [apparently](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=18443) only works with `biblatex`.

Can I mimic the output needed in my case (ie: no `biblatex`)?

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding something, but why can you just write: `(this is the first source \cite{Smith_2000}; and also see \cite{Smith_2013} for more)`?

Comment: Because that would mean I end up with parentheses within parentheses, which is bad practice I believe (at least I don't like it) But your comment gave me the idea of using `\citealp` which does precisely that. If you'd like you can put that in the form of an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Glad that you found a solution. I briefly tried to work out how to extract the necessary information from the `\cite` command, but wasn't able to get anything to work. I think that as you found the solution I can't post it as "my" solution. Wouldn't it would be fairer if you posted your solution and then accepted it?

Comment: @Andrew well I only came up with `\citealp` after you mentioned another way to come up with a similar output using `\cite`, so from where I stand the solution should be given to you. In any case, if you feel it'd be better if I post it myself, I will.

Answer (score 4):

Since no one wants to post an answer, I don't mind if I do.

This worked for me:

```
(this is the first source \citealt{Smith_2000}; and also see \citealt{Smith_2013} for more)
```

Notice the lack of commas between the author and date.  For commas use `\citealp{}` instead of `\citealt`.  I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102532/citealp-putting-parentheses-in-citation-inappropriately/102549#102549) comparison of functions helpful as well.